# Adding items to an object is taking too long

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a method that builds out an array of objects (list) and returns it to the parent.  I was having a terrible time with the performance in my MVC app so I decided to add a stopwatch in place to catch of various areas of the code which is being called.  I've now isolated it down to this area:
                var items = new List();

```
            _stopwatch.Start();

            var query = (from img in db.links
                         join link in db.lScc on img.pkID equals link.nLinkConfig
                         select new
                         {
                             ImageBase64 = img.bzImage,
                             ImageType = img.szImageType,
                             Description = img.szDescription,
                             URL = img.szURI,
                             HrefTarget = img.nWindowBehavior,
                             GroupName = link.szGroupName,
                             LinkConfig = link.nLinkConfig
                         }).DistinctBy(x => x.LinkConfig);
            _stopwatch.Stop();

            _stopwatch.Start();

            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                    items.Add(new
                    {
                        ImageBase64 = item.ImageBase64 != null && item.ImageBase64.Length > 0 ? Convert.ToBase64String(item.ImageBase64) : "",
                        ImageType = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ImageType) ? "" : item.ImageType,
                        Description = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Description) ? "" : item.Description,
                        URL = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.URL) ? "" : item.URL,
                        HrefTarget = item.HrefTarget,
                        GroupName = item.GroupName
                    });
            }
            _stopwatch.Stop(); // takes around 11 seconds for this to complete about 20 iterations
```

I first thought it may be the ...Convert.ToBase64String(item.ImageBase64)... but I commented that out and it had basically no effect.

Anyone have any ideas what could be causing the slowness?   This should only take a fraction of a second to complete.  It deals with UI so this needs to be a lot more responsive.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, your `query` is lazy loaded or already in memory? If it's lazy loaded, it means in every iteration of foreach, the database is being queried, that will take very long overall.

Comment: You should continue your comment-out approach until you isolate the line. I'm suprised you didnt'

Comment: How many items in query?

Comment: How large are the `ImageBase64` objects?  Are we talking KB or MB or GB?  Have you timed the query execution by itself?

Comment: Yes, I tried each section of code out with a stopwatch and reported it out to logging.  I also commented out each line of the adding variables to a new list object.  The query itself is fast and it completes quickly.  I'm not sure it's lazy because when I inspect I see all lines there.  If there is an image, we're talking about 50k.  But again, I removed that and the other lines to no avail.  I updated the above code with the query.

Comment: You know, this may be caused by lazy loading based on what I'm reading as it's default.  I'm not really understanding how to turn it off though?

Comment: I found another SO article that said to set the LazyLoadingEnabled = false; (db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; // set before the query) but it didn't have any bearing on the speed.

Comment: Remember .Start and .Stop doesn't actually reset the timer.

Comment: What is the `items` in the loop? a `List` or `DbSet` ?

Comment: I know.  That's a product of cutting and pasting the code twice for the start and stop.  There is a reset there, just missed it on the second copy.

the items are type dbset.

Comment: So when you commented out lines bit by bit, which one was the issue? You say `var items = new List();`, but that code isn't in your sample

Comment: Its the block of code I have commented which is the issue.  It's creating a new list item for the list "items"; see the comments.

Comment: Remove items.Add() line, see if there is any improvement. If you don't, probably it is the tables. Not having proper indices for the join.

Comment: Do this, var queryArr = query.ToArray() in the first block. use queryArr in the for loop. This narrow down the issue lies in the list construction or at the db.

Comment: I've already done that with the same results.  I also have verified the indexes to exist on the tables.  

I should also mention this was slightly slow previously when it was a local server.  This problem amplified (x5) when I pushed it out into Azure.  The lazy loading really seems to fit the bill here but it sure looks like I have it disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks to be that you want to load all items from a db into the query and not lazy load the results. The round trip to the db can be very slow.

```
        var query = (from img in db.links
                     join link in db.lScc on img.pkID equals link.nLinkConfig
                     select new
                     {
                         ImageBase64 = img.bzImage,
                         ImageType = img.szImageType,
                         Description = img.szDescription,
                         URL = img.szURI,
                         HrefTarget = img.nWindowBehavior,
                         GroupName = link.szGroupName,
                         LinkConfig = link.nLinkConfig
                     }).DistinctBy(x => x.LinkConfig);
query.count();
```

query.count  will load all the items at once into your collection rather than lazy load your collection

Comment: I was hopeful on this, I tried it and I still have the same speed issue.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there was something wrong with my datamodel so the this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false set in the model.edmx wasn't disabling the lazy loading.  I updated the model from the database and fixed the issue (there was a deleted table that kept coming back) and re-tried.  It's now 1/4 the time previously.  Thanks for the tips on this!